# Protocol for adjusting UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

In every one of my view controllers I'm calling a function that edits the appearance of my navigation controller and the text of the left/right buttons.  Instead of having this code in every view controller, i'm trying to implement a protocol that each view controller conforms to.

Current code in every view controller:

```
func setupNavReg(backButtonText: String, nextButtonText: String)
{
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)

    let leftNavButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: backButtonText, style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("backButtonPressed"))
    let customFont = UIFont(name: "Gill Sans", size: 14.0)

    leftNavButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:customFont!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavButton

    //nextButton left out for     
}
```

Protocol Design

```
protocol navBarInterface {
    var navigationController: UINavigationController? { get }
    func configureWithBackButton(backButtonText: String, nextButtonText: String)
}

extension navBarInterface {
    func configureWithBackButton(backButtonText: String, nextButtonText: String) {

    if let navigationController = navigationController {
        navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        let customFont = UIFont(name: "Gill Sans", size: 14.0)

        let leftNavButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: backButtonText, style: .Plain, target: nil, action: Selector("backButtonPressed"))
        leftNavButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        leftNavButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:customFont!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavButton  

        //nextButton left out 
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I'm unable to get this to work.  The appearance of the navigation controller isn't changing but I see that the protocol break points I've set are getting hit when the view controller appears.  I'm also concerned I'm not going to be able to hit the selector functions when the nav buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If this protocol only applies to `UINavigationController`'s, then I would forget about the protocol and just define an extension on `UINavigationController`:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func configureWithBackButton(backButtonText: String, nextButtonText: String) {
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        let customFont = UIFont(name: "Gill Sans", size: 14.0)

        let leftNavButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: Selector("backButtonPressed"))
        leftNavButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        leftNavButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:customFont!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavButton  

        //nextButton left out 
    }
}
```

I only say that because protocols sometimes interact in funky ways with classes and subclasses - i.e., what happens if your class defines the method, but the protocol defines it as well, etc. So try extending the class and see if that solves the problem.

I also noticed that your code is different - in the original method, `setupNavReg`, you set the text of the back button to `backButtonText`, but in your extension you set it to `"Back"`. Is that intentional? It may be why the text isn't changing to whatever string you are passing to the method...

Comment: Tried this out but I'm getting the same results.  Where do you think it should be called.  in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I edited my answer to add another suggestion. And yes, I think `viewDidLoad` is the right place to call this.

Comment: Sorry for that.  That was just sloppy editing on my part.  setUpNavReg was my old approach and has be commented out.  I'm passing in a string for each of the button titles.